# Показать loader в момент передачи данных на сервер

Tags: jquery

Есть такая ajax функция

```
function searchPromokode(){
            var promokode= $(".promokode").val();
            if(promokode.length>13){

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/search/promokode",
                data: "promokode="+promokode,
                success: function(answer) {
                   if (answer){
                    alert('Промокод активирован');
                   } else {
                    alert('Промокод уже был активирован');
                   }
                }
                });

            }
        }
```

Хочу поставить loader допустим

```
<div class="loader"></div>

.loader{
display:none;
}
```

Есть два вопроса, в какой момент поставить показ этого loader в ajax запросе. И второй, я конечно понимаю мы все хотим ускорить процесс всей работы, но я так понимаю обработка будет очень быстрой, меньше секунды и пользователь не увидит loader, простите за тупейший вопрос НО как поставить задержку в 1-2 секунды что бы лоадер покрутился)

Comment: ставить надо не в запросе, а перед ним. а по завершению убирать. искусственное увеличение времени ожидания хз зачем нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы loader хоть чуть-чуть покрутился, можете добавить ег ов момент success, а сам результат success сделаете с задержкой через setTimeout, а вообще обычно лоадеры ставят в событие ajaxSend

```
function searchPromokode(){
            var promokode= $(".promokode").val();
            if(promokode.length>13){

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/search/promokode",
                data: "promokode="+promokode,
                success: function(answer) {
                   // тут добавляем лоадер
                   setTimeout(function () {
                   // тут убираем лоадер
                   if (answer){
                    alert('Промокод активирован');
                   } else {
                    alert('Промокод уже был активирован');
                   }}, 2000);
                }
                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: как-то забавно включать лоадер, когда результат запроса уже пришел обратно, вы так не считаете? :D включать его надо перед отправкой запроса, тогда он покрутится ровно столько, сколько выполняется запрос.

Comment: Вы прочитайте сначала вопрос ТС, потом внимательно мой ответ перед кодом, а потом подумайте, стоило ли оставлять этот коммент

Comment: одно другому не мешает. запрос может выполняться некоторое время, и в этом момент у пользователя будет белый экран. в любом случае, хоть ставить задержку хоть нет, лоадер должен быть показан перед сами запросом. Если требуется минимальное время показа, добавлять таймштамп и проверять, сколько выполнялся запрос, отнимая это время из желаемых 2сек.

Comment: хотя с другой стороны, вы упомянули про `ajaxSend`, не понятно почему не реализовали именно так

Comment: потому что судя по коду и самому вопросу у автора не стоит задача в функциональности, и в данном случае во главе угла стоит именно "Хочу чтобы лоадер крутился подольше, потому что это красиво и эффектно", если такая задача встанет, то он сможет вбить в гугле ajaxSend и узнать об этом подробней. И в моем ответе задача была скорее показать принцип и указать в какую сторону копать, чем показать сам код